# How to test a crossplatform app

Tags: javascript, html, css, cordova, visual-studio-cordova

I've just "finshed" my app using Visual Studio and Cordova, how can i do an early test of it? I'd like to test it on a smartphone, without publishing it on the stores. The app is for android, iOS and win phone.

Comment: If you have PhoneGap's CLI set up then use `phonegap serve` this can then be accessed using the PhoneGap Developer app (which you can download from an app store) by typing in the name of the web server generated with the `phonegap serve` command. This is generally good for checking out the look and feel of your app quickly and easily

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends, is your app Android, iOS or Windows Phone?

You should edit that in your post.

Now, in Visual Studio you have different types of emulators that could help you with that, and if it is a simple app you can test it that way and everything should work.

Or you can connect your Android to your computer and test it and even debug it (and iOS involves having a Mac).

Check [here](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/6.x/guide/platforms/android/index.html#configure-an-emulator) (example for android) the documentation on Cordova and they explain it rather well.

But your still should search more about the topic on the internet, there is tons of information about this topic.

Comment: I wrote it's a crossplatform app, which means it works with android, apple and winPhone. By the way what I'm looking for is testing it on my nexus 5 :)

Comment: My bad, i wrote crossover instead of crossplatform :P

Comment: Of course and crossplatform could just be android and iOS, it is good to be as specific as possible.

Check the link I left for emulators and 
[this one](http://geeklearning.io/apache-cordova-and-remote-debugging-on-android/) for your physical device.

Comment: When i change simulation terminal to device, it displays an error: `cmd: Command failed with exit code 2 BlankCordovaApp2`

Comment: @FrancescoMonti, Build, just build in Visual Studio then

Install [ADB](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?p=48915118#post48915118) (Android Debug Bridge) and navigate to the instalation folder and run cmd.

Use the command adb install <your app location>\platforms\android\build\outputs\apk\android-debug.apk

Comment: it displays "invalid apk file"

Comment: do you already have your device in debug mode? [link](http://geeklearning.io/apache-cordova-and-remote-debugging-on-android/)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105279/discussion-between-break7533-and-francesco-monti).